# Leader Board Score submission

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I would like to know how the google play services leader boards interprets the following events.The developer guide doesn't seems to have a detailed explanation regarding this.

DAY1 10:00 AM  ==> SCORE 100 submitted to leader board

DAY1  10:30AM ===> SCORE 50 submitted to leader board

DAY2 10:00AM==> SCORE 75 submitted to leaderboard

DAY2 10:30AM==> SCORE 55 submitted to leaderboard

DAY3 10:00AM==> SCORE 105 submitted to leaderboard

DAY3 10:30AM==> SCORE 55 submitted to leaderboard

Question1: What will be the Daily HighScore of DAY2 ? 100 OR 75 ?

Question2: I am storing the high score locally. 
Is there any use in submitting the low scores other than the high score(Eg:-DAY2 Scores and DAY3 10:30AM score)?,otherwise which i can save  the usage quota ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

The leaderboard timeframes are based on the pacific time zone. See https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#leaderboard_time_frames.

> Daily leaderboards reset at midnight PST every day, and weekly
>   leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST.

So the answer to your first question depends on the player's timezone. If the player is in California, then the daily day2 score would be 75.

There is no benefit in submitting a score you know to be lower, they are just ignored. Usually it is more simple to just submit it so you don't have to keep track of the score yourself, but your approach will work as well.